# how can i create a countdown timer where the user inputs any number and display it from that number to zero?

Tags: javascript, timer

How can I create a countdown timer where the user inputs a time in seconds and display it from that number to zero in javascript?

```
var userChoice = parseInt(prompt("Type in time to countdown")); 
var timer = setInterval(countDown, 1000); 

// this is what i have 
function countDown() { 
   console.log(counter); 
   counter--; 
   if (counter < 0) { 
      clearInterval(timer); 
      console.log("END"); 
   }
}
```

Comment: var userChoice = parseInt(prompt("Type in time to countdown"));
var timer = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
this is what i have










function countDown() {
 console.log(counter);
 counter--;
 if (counter < 0) {
  clearInterval(timer);
  console.log("END");
 }
}

Comment: How fun -> `var t=prompt("Type in time to countdown");(function w(){document.body.innerHTML=t--;if(t) setTimeout(w,800);})();` [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XM5PH/1)

Comment: adeneo it becomes super fun if you enter 9.4 or any decimal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake was: `counter` is never defined. Replace it with `userChoice` and it works perfectly the way you did it:

```
var userChoice = parseInt(prompt("Type in time to countdown")); 
var timer = setInterval(countDown, 1000); 

function countDown() { 
   console.log(userChoice); 
   userChoice--; 
   if (userChoice < 0) { 
      clearInterval(timer); 
      console.log("END"); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The timer only fires once.  Be sure to place the following line at the end of your countDown function so it will get called again:

```
timer = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
```